# Not able to click on Spam mail in Gmail account using Webdriver Selenium

Tags: selenium

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.ProfilesIni;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Firefox_Profiling {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        ProfilesIni allProfs = new ProfilesIni(); 
        //All the Firefox profiles on the machine are loaded in 'allProfs' object automatically.
        FirefoxProfile myprofile = allProfs.getProfile("Selenium");
        //getProfile function will return an object of an Internal class known as FirefoxProfile
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(myprofile);
        //Selenium Firefox profile will be opening from your local machine.


        driver.get("http://gmail.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='gmail-sign-in']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='Email']")).sendKeys("abhishek114p");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("xxxxxxx");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='signIn']")).click();

        Thread.sleep(7000);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=':jh']/div/div[1]/span/a")).click();




    }
}
```

I was trying to click spam mail to see the spam mails but I was not able to do so. All the statements above are working fine except the last one.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use IMAP to get email since it's GUI Free. You can take a look at this for more information

http://www.seleniumtests.com/2011/08/verify-email-confirmation-using.html

http://www.abodeqa.com/2014/06/28/email-verification-gmail-account-selenium-webdriver-java/

Edit:

As three_pineapples' and Todd's suggestion. I just left the reference links. Hope they are last long enough to help the asker to solve his/her problem.

Comment: The answer is there - use the Gmail API. That in itself (the API implementation) could change over time, and even an in-answer quotation could become outdated. The links are useful, as of the time of writing. Perhaps a Google Search link would last longer. Also, you might want to suggest IMAP to view SPAM folder, rather than a specialised Gmail API.

Comment: What license is the code you have posted under? Unless it is compatible with the Creative Commons license, you should not be posting it here. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/12539

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered many times; do not try and automate Gmail.

Scenario 1; I need to access Gmail data automatically.

Response; Use the Gmail API to access programatically

Scenario 2: I am trying to learn Selenium and have chosen Gmail as my example page

Response; Don't! There are many other simpler websites out there to practice automating on.  Gmail is a challenge for experienced automators

Answer (score 0):

First you need to click "More"(xpath = "//span[text()='More']") for "Spam" (partialLinkText = "Spam") link to appear in menu. Partial link text because number of Spam messages is added to it. Also you may submit "in:spam" to search input at your mailbox page.